# Función IIF, cómo hacer para que tome 2N + 1 argumentos de expresiones lógicas?, C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, función-personalizada

En Visual Basic existe está **[Función IIF](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function)**, al igual en Crystal Report, etc...

En C# propiamente no existe esta función, pero es lo mismo que hacer algo como esto:

```
bool a = true;
string b = a ? "Verdadero" : "Falso";
```

Pero para que el código sea un poco mas fácil de leer quisé hacerlo como una función para C#, quedando de esta manera:

```
public static T IIf<T>(bool Condicion, T ParteVerdadera, T ParteFalsa) 
{
     return Condicion ? ParteVerdadera : ParteFalsa;
}
```

O para que no opere con los valores reales también se puede hacer usando delegados, para acceder a los valores necesarios:

```
public static T IIf<T>(bool Condicion, Func<T> ParteVerdadera, Func<T> ParteFalsa) 
{
    return Condicion ? ParteVerdadera() : ParteFalsa();
}
```

Hasta aquí esto funciona bien...

---

Pero **Cómo puedo modificar está función para que pueda tomar 2N + 1 argumentos?**

> (N - el número de expresiones lógicas especificadas)

Ejemplo el resultado deseado:

```
int valor = IIf(Nombre = "Joel", 1, Nombre = "Pedro", 2, Nombre = "Maria", 3, 4);
```

Alguién puede darme una mano con esto?

Entorno: C# - Visual Studio 2017

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu motivación en convertir el operador ternario `?:` en una función? me parece algo interesante.

Comment: @Xam Pensaba que resultaría más fácil para mi usarla de esta manera, pero creo que debo abandonar está idea, me comentaron que es una mala práctica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a responder a mi propia pregunta solo por si a otra persona le es de interés, basado en respuestas que me proporcionaron en SO Inglés, aunque encontré el resultado esperado, prácticamente opté por abandonar esta idea, debido que fue considerada como una mala práctica.

**Método 1:**

Si se quiere conservar el orden de los parámetros, se puede hacer algo como esto:

```
public T IIf<T>(params object[] objects) 
{
    for(var i = 0; i < objects.Length - 1; i += 2) 
        if((bool)objects[i])
           return (T)objects[i+1];

    return (T)objects[objects.Length - 1];
}
```

Se debe declarar explícitamente el tipo con el que está trabajando. Así que tendrías que usarlo así:

```
int valor = IIf<int>(Nombre = "Joel", 1, Nombre = "Pedro", 2, Nombre = "Maria", 3, 4);
```

Si observamos el paso de `int` como un parámetro de tipo. Esto se puede evitar cambiando el orden de los parámetros para que el valor predeterminado sea lo primero.

Pero, si solo estamos dispuesto a adoptar un patrón personal, la sintaxis ternaria anidada puede ser bastante legible:

```
int valor = 
      Nombre == "Joel" ? 1
    : Nombre == "Pedro" ? 2
    : Nombre == "Maria" ? 3
    : 4;
```

---

**Método 2:**

En primer lugar, en los comentarios que obtuve, esta es una mala idea porque las versiones más nuevas de C# ya son compatibles con los interruptores de coincidencia de patrones como una característica integrada del lenguaje.

Segundo, esta es una mala idea porque la API de "argumento, caso1, resultado1, caso2, resultado2, ..." tiene una firma que es difícil de expresar en el sistema de tipo C#.

Pero de igual forma si fuese obligatorio implementar dicha API, sugeriría usar tuplas:

```
public static R Switch<A, R>(A item, R theDefault, params (A, R)[] cases )
{
    foreach(var c in cases) 
        if (item.Equals(c.Item1))
            return c.Item2;
    return theDefault;
}
```

O bien, hacer un método de más utilidad:

```
public static T FirstOrDefault(this IEnumerable<T> items, T theDefault, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach(var i in items.Where(predicate))
      return i;
    return theDefault;
} 

public static R Switch<A, R>(A item, R theDefault, params (A, R)[] cases ) =>
      cases.FirstOrDefault(
          (item, theDefault), 
           c => item.Equals(c.Item1)).Item2;
```

Si no puede usar tuplas porque está usando una versión anterior de C#, puede crear su propio tipo de par o usar el tipo de par clave-valor.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es llamar de forma recursiva a la misma funcion IIF, de esta manera mantienes el codigo limpio y facil de leer, asi:

```
int valor = IIf(Nombre = "Joel", 1, IIf(Nombre = "Marco", 2, IIf(Nombre = "Pedro", 3, 4)));
```

Comment: Gracias ya había pensado en esto, pero no es el resultado que deseo.